# How do I store a value in a global variable and then use it in subsequent steps of a scenario in protractor cucumber typescript based project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber, angular, typescript

I want to retrieve a value in 'Given' function and then store it in a global variable so that the value is accessible in subsequent steps of a scenario in protractor cucumber typescript based automation project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your conf.js file and create an onPrepare function, there you can define and initialize a global variable. Below is a sample:

```
exports.config = {
        directConnect: true,
        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome'
        },
        framework: 'jasmine',
        baseUrl: "http://url.com",
        specs: ['./*_specs.js'],

        onPrepare: function() {
            browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
            //create a global variable like below
global.variableName = "hello";
        }
}
```